# CSS links and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of trouble with styling by active links, and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="sup">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#home" title="Home" class="home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#work" title="Work" class="work">Work</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#about" title="About" class="about">About</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#skills" title="Skills" class="skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#contact" title="Contact" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 431px;
    float: right;
}

#navbar {
    clear:       both;
    width:       959px;
    margin:      0 auto;
    height:      40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#navigation ul {
    margin:              0;
    padding:             0;
    list-style:          none;
    background-image:    url(images/navi-bg.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat:   repeat;
}

#navigation li {
    text-align:  center;
    float:       left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#navigation li a {
    outline:         none;
    font-size:       18px;
    color:           #939393;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    -moz-border-radius:    4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius:      4px;
    -ms-border-radius:     4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:  4px;
    border-radius:         4px;
    background-color:      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042);
    border:                1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    color:                 #2D2D2D;
    margin:                0;
    border-image:          initial;
    padding-left:          7px;
    padding-right:         7px;
    padding-top:           3px;
    padding-bottom:        3px;
}

#navigation li a:active {
    -moz-border-radius:    4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius:      4px;
    -ms-border-radius:     4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:  4px;
    border-radius:         4px;
    background-color:      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.042);
    border:                1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    margin:                0;
    border-image:          initial;
    padding-left:          7px;
    padding-right:         7px;
    padding-top:           3px;
    padding-bottom:        3px;
    color:                 #939393;
}
```

The JQUERY:

```
function loadStuff() {

    $("a").click(function () {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');

        $(".menu a").each(function () {
            $(this).css("color", "#939393");
        });

        if (link == "#home") {
            $("a.home").css("color", "#939393");
        }

        if (link == "#about") {
            $("a.about").css({"background-color":"yellow", "color":"#939393"});
        }

        if (link == "#work") {
            $("a.work").css("color", "#939393");

        }


        if (link == "#skills") {
            $("a.skills").css("color", "#939393");

        }

        if (link == "#contact") {
            $("a.contact").css("color", "#939393");
        }

        if (link == "#contact") {
            $("a.career").css("color", "#3d6b7b");
        }

    });
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is have a border on the active link and a yellow background.  I have managed to get it working on the 'about' active link, however when I click on a different link the yellow background still shows on the 'about' link and I only want it to show when it's active.

Comment: If your Javascript code had indentation, you would notice that you are missing the closing `}` of your `$("a").click(function () {` -- EDIT -- Sorry, my bad. You're missing the closing `}` of `loadStuff`.

Comment: Basically you need two css classes. One is for active link and another is for inactive link. Whenever user clicks on any link just apply the active class to the link that the user has clicked and apply inactive class to the rest of the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` on click.

I've edited you code - http://jsfiddle.net/wqNmT/

Al

Comment: Thanks mate, its appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the `bg_color` each time. You are adding a bg_color, that doesn't mean that you are removing it to the rest of the links when you click on `$(this)`.
[Alex Thomas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464135/1100238) is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at :
http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/else/cssnav/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you are using #menu that is for an id, you have `class="menu"` so in your CSS you have to use

```
.menu {

}
```